# Return only one value from JObject with two values in it C#

Tags: c#

How can I return only one of those values in response of method not both of them.

```
        return new JObject
        {
            ["accepted"] = acceptedArr,
            ["declined"] = declinedArr
        };
```

I mean if I want to return only the value of acceptedArr ,not to display both of them like

```
         { "acceptedArr": 
            ["some info"], 
          "declinedArr": [] }
```

Comment: What do you mean `return only one of those values `?

Comment: I mean if I want to return only the value of acceptedArr ,not to display both of them like 

{
  "acceptedArr": ["some info"],
  "declinedArr": []
}

Comment: I think to help you out we need more specific information

Comment: `var jsonResponse = new JObject {
            ["accepted"] = acceptedArr,
            ["declined"] = declinedArr
        };  return jsonResponse["accepted"];`

Comment: Using ternary you can do this way  var result = accepted ? jObject["accepted"] = acceptedArr : jObject["declined"] = declinedArr;
   //alter
   var result2 = accepted ? jObject.Remove("accepted") : jObject.Remove("declined");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally populate the properties you want by first creating an empty `jObject` and then assigning the appropriate property based on some condition:

```
var jObject = new JObject();

if (accepted)
{
    jObject["accepted"] = acceptedArr;
}
else
{
    jObject["declined"] = declinedArr;
}

return jObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object was created already before your code starts, then you can remove the property that you don't want:

```
public JObject SomeMethod(JObject obj)
{
    if ( /* condition here */ )
    {
        obj.Remove("accepted");
    }
    else
    {
        obj.Remove("declined");
    }
    return obj;
}
```